# why does tcpdump shows 16 '0x00' bytes at the end of UDP packets？

Tags: tcpdump, libpcap

I use Tcpdump in different machine with different version.
And i notice that there are 16 0x00 bytes at the end of UDP packets in a higher tcpdump version. AnyBody know why?

Machine A with

tcpdump version 4.1-PRE-CVS_2012_03_26

libpcap version 1.0.0

```
12:12:26.363084 IP 100.65.96.185.38431 > 10.100.71.207.54404: UDP, length 121
0x0000:  3897 d6b1 e3c1 5452 0092 f8ae 0800 4500  8.....TR......E.
0x0010:  0095 b0fd 4000 4011 722d 6441 60b9 0a64  ....@.@.r-dA`..d
0x0020:  47cf 961f d484 0081 17c0 2800 0000 0000  G.........(.....
0x0030:  0000 6f08 6412 6b08 0110 5318 0020 ebb1  ..o.d.k...S.....
0x0040:  d6b9 0730 a7f0 f7d2 0538 9891 b5d0 0a40  ...0.....8.....@
0x0050:  9891 b5d0 0a48 0172 3a0a 380a 1b08 0010  .....H.r:.8.....
0x0060:  a7f0 f7d2 0518 a4af e8e6 0e20 0028 0930  .............(.0
0x0070:  0038 8601 4000 4a00 1213 0a11 0a0f 6a61  .8..@.J.......ja
0x0080:  736f 6e2d 636f 6e66 2d74 6573 7412 044a  son-conf-test..J
0x0090:  0208 0080 0101 8801 0090 01b4 b3ee 7e98  ..............~.
0x00a0:  0101 29                                  ..)
```

Machine B with

tcpdump version 4.5.1

libpcap version 1.5.3

```
12:12:26.353267 IP 100.65.96.185.38431 > 10.100.71.207.54404: UDP, length 121
0x0000:  4560 0095 b0fd 4000 3a11 77cd 6441 60b9  E`....@.:.w.dA`.
0x0010:  0a64 47cf 961f d484 0081 8065 2800 0000  .dG........e(...
0x0020:  0000 0000 6f08 6412 6b08 0110 5318 0020  ....o.d.k...S...
0x0030:  ebb1 d6b9 0730 a7f0 f7d2 0538 9891 b5d0  .....0.....8....
0x0040:  0a40 9891 b5d0 0a48 0172 3a0a 380a 1b08  .@.....H.r:.8...
0x0050:  0010 a7f0 f7d2 0518 a4af e8e6 0e20 0028  ...............(
0x0060:  0930 0038 8601 4000 4a00 1213 0a11 0a0f  .0.8..@.J.......
0x0070:  6a61 736f 6e2d 636f 6e66 2d74 6573 7412  jason-conf-test.
0x0080:  044a 0208 0080 0101 8801 0090 01b4 b3ee  .J..............
0x0090:  7e98 0101 2900 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ~...)...........
0x00a0:  0000 0000 00
```

Comment: That looks like a bug.  If you look at the UDP length and the IP datagram length, the output should have ended at 0x95, which is the 0x29 byte.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a bug.  If you look at the UDP length and the IP datagram length, the output should have ended at `0x95`, which is the `0x29` byte.

The IP length in the packet is `0x0095`, which is 149 bytes.

The UDP length is `0x0081`, which is 129.

20 byte IP header + 129 bytes of UDP data brings us to 149, which matches 0x95.  TCPDump should not be showing those last few bytes.

Comment: By the way, have you looked at the same packets with Wireshark?  I'm curious to see what it shows.  There is a slim possibility that the ethernet framing is 802.2 and indicates that the data length from the ethernet frame's perspective is longer than what IP is set to.